# Exported modules returns undefined when used react's syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module, undefined, next.js

I'm using **next.js** and **Typescript**, everything compiles fine, when I try to follow any page I see in console (*SSR* from next) errors which occurred by undefined imports.

I got that any *.tsx* file that contains react-syntax (`<div />`) returns undefined if imported as module. And even if I don't export the component and try to export something else (like `string`) it still returns undefined.

If I use statefull component and return `null` from renderer - it works fine and module returns function.

My **.babelrc**:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel",
    "@zeit/next-typescript/babel"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-styled-components",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      { "legacy": true }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      { "loose": true }
    ],
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "alias": {
          "Components": "./build/components",
          "UI": "./build/uikit",
          "Utils": "./build/utils",
          "Hooks": "./build/hooks",
          "Contexts": "./build/contexts"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript",
        [
          "module-resolver",
          {
            "alias": {
              "Components": "./src/components",
              "UI": "./src/uikit",
              "Utils": "./src/utils",
              "Hooks": "./src/hooks",
              "Contexts": "./src/contexts",
              "Models": "./src/models",
              "Mocks": "./src/__mocks__"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/**/*.d.ts"],
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "./build",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "Components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
            "Utils/*": ["./src/utils/*"],
            "Hooks/*": ["./src/hooks/*"],
            "UI/*": ["./src/uikit/*"],
            "Contexts/*": ["./src/contexts/*"],
            "Models/*": ["./src/models/*"],
            "Mocks/*": ["./src/__mocks__/*"]
        },
        "allowJs": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["./node_modules"]
}
```

**next.config.js** is regular one, nothing used to extend functionality.

Previously everything worked fine, but I've integrated eslint instead of tslint and had much corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by changing tsconfig.json parameter target to es2020 and module to esnext, so for some reason it works fine now.
I had the problem above because I need to parse ts to es5 because I start the server by regular node command ./server/index.js (no imports will be understand).
So now I have 2 tsconfig.json files with server and client configurations